# send null values during serialisation

Tags: vb.net

Trying to determine best way to seralize so I can send in a null value for middle name if not entered

My xml:

```
<Contact>
    <ID />
    <First_Name />
    <Middle_Name  xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
    <Last_Name />
    <TelephoneNumbers>
        <TelephoneNumber>
            <Number />
            <IsHome />
            <IsWork />
            <IsCell />
            <ReachableAfterHrs />
        </TelephoneNumber>
    </TelephoneNumbers>
 </Contact>
```

The vb class created for serialization/deserialisation

```
'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="", IsNullable:=False)> _
Partial Public Class Contact

    Private idField As String

    Private first_NameField As String

    Private middle_NameField As ContactMiddle_Name

    Private last_NameField As String

    Private telephoneNumbersField As ContactTelephoneNumbers

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property ID() As String
        Get
            Return Me.idField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.idField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property First_Name() As String
        Get
            Return Me.first_NameField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.first_NameField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property Middle_Name() As ContactMiddle_Name
        Get
            Return Me.middle_NameField
        End Get
        Set(value As ContactMiddle_Name)
            Me.middle_NameField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property Last_Name() As String
        Get
            Return Me.last_NameField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.last_NameField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property TelephoneNumbers() As ContactTelephoneNumbers
        Get
            Return Me.telephoneNumbersField
        End Get
        Set(value As ContactTelephoneNumbers)
            Me.telephoneNumbersField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)> _
Partial Public Class ContactMiddle_Name

    Private nilField As Boolean

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, [Namespace]:="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")> _
    Public Property nil() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.nilField
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            Me.nilField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)> _
Partial Public Class ContactTelephoneNumbers

    Private telephoneNumberField As ContactTelephoneNumbersTelephoneNumber

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property TelephoneNumber() As ContactTelephoneNumbersTelephoneNumber
        Get
            Return Me.telephoneNumberField
        End Get
        Set(value As ContactTelephoneNumbersTelephoneNumber)
            Me.telephoneNumberField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)> _
Partial Public Class ContactTelephoneNumbersTelephoneNumber

    Private numberField As Object

    Private isHomeField As Object

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property Number() As Object
        Get
            Return Me.numberField
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            Me.numberField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property IsHome() As Object
        Get
            Return Me.isHomeField
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            Me.isHomeField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Upon deserialising, the output contains tag which represents an empty element rather then a null. The client wants us to send null rather then empty.

Comment: Is there a special reason all your fields are declared as objects instead of strongly typed as strings or some other class?

Comment: Crickey, that was done by VS2013 when I did paste as special. I pasted that code, but I have changed mine to Strings instead of Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving the properties the following attribute `<XmlElement(IsNullable := True)>`.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry, I had a copy/paste error earlier where the attribute was originally set to `false`.

Comment: Doing so gets me thsi ` <Middle_Name d3p1:nil="false" xmlns:d3p1="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Smith</Middle_Name>` if middle name is set. and not sure where it gets d3p1 instead of xsi

Comment: I'm not sure why it choose to rename the schema, but I believe it is still syntactically correct according to the rules of xml

Comment: Is there a way that I can not get the nil elements in the serialised xml? Would be better if i omit the null elements altogether in my xml